# how to get the installed software location in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

How to search for the installed software location (complete directory structure) by its name. Is there any command through which i can get complete details of all the file locations of the corrosponding software installed.

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather say `dpkg -L {package}`, as it's about Debian/Ubuntu. Got [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/dpkg-cheat-sheet.php).

Comment: But dpkg -L {package} shows the package installed by the synaptics package manager only. I installed some software which is not in synaptics package manager, how can i get that package installed location

Comment: Also by Software center and GDebi :)

Comment: But yes. If it wasn't a deb package, you're left with `whereis`.
You can even install software by bare copying files, then you can only find its main binary with `which <binary name>`: there's no way system will know of other files.
Or if you used `alien`, you can look it up.
Or if you used "make install", then it's probably in spread over `/usr/local/` subdirectories.
But `dpkg` is the main Ubuntu way.

Answer (score 1):

`whereis thissoftware`  (eg: `whereis perl`)  will do it for individual, named apps.

Comment: @dsharma: As an example, `whereis perl` doesn't show `/usr/share/man/man1/cpan.1.gz` (and many more) while Victor's answer does.